# Load slideshow.css file only if Slideshow is checked / on

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, css, conditional-tags

I use

```
<?php if ( get_option('mytheme_slider') == 'checked') { get_template_part( 'partials/slider/slider-java-script' ); } ?>
```

to include the slider-java-script.php template part into my site. Works fine.

How can i include or load my **slider-java-script.css** file if the same option is checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function to your functions.php file like this:

```
function slider_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slider-java-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slider-java-script.css' ); //change the location to work for you
}
```

Then add slider_scripts() to the top of the template part ( partials/slider/slider-java-script.php )